# How large are the CF-100 Canuck wingtip fuel tanks?

Tags: fuel-tanks, avro-cf-100

How big are the CF-100 Canuck's wingtip fuel tanks and what is the maximum fuel capacity they can carry?

Answer (score 3):

This diagram from the [RCAF Canuck Aircraft Operating Instructions](https://www.avialogs.com/cf-100-canuck/item/56150-eo-05-25da-1-aircraft-operating-instructions-cf-100-mk3d) states the wingtip tanks could each hold up to 292 imperial gallons or 350 US gallons.

[image: CF-100 Canuck Mk 3D Fuel System Diagram]